# Make background dark when a specific widget is Seleted

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-listview

I am working on Flutter Project where I want to achieve a functionality where whenever a user selects an item (via Tap or LongPress) from `ListView.builder()` or `GridView.builder()`. That widget should be highlighted and the background should turn a bit dark.

Here you can see that how it should look like:

[image]

I've tried to achieve it using Backdrop Filter as well as Overlay but both are giving different kind of output.

**Using Backdrop Filter**: When I tried to blur background using `BackDropFilter`, it turned half of the page blur and half of the portion was unlbur.

Here's the reference code:

```js
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(
              sigmaX: index == 2 ? 10 : 0,
              sigmaY: index == 2 ? 10 : 0,
            ),
            child: const MessageCard(),
          );
        },
      )
```

I also tried using overlay but then I am not able to select multiple items because the screen touch is disabled when an overlay it open.

Is there any custom way or package that we can implement to achive this result?

Comment: you can achieve this with hero animation, [more info](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/animations/hero-animations)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on it as I am not getting your point.

Comment: you can design new page which contains  all the widget inside the right image and when ever the action called you push to new page with hero animation. It will like that the item in you list highlighted.

Comment: Ok, I got it, but that way the position will be fixed. When I long press on a certain widget, how I will be able to send the position to another screen?

Comment: that is the part that come with hero animation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this `package` for highlight widget and changed `barrier color`
https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview
[image]

Comment: I tried forking this package and making it custom but it doesn't allow me to multi-select widgets.

Comment: You can locally download and modify package class by locally right